# Not getting complete data during conversion of series to string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a series into string but unable to get complete information during this.

Input data:-

```
      tweets
0   ['automotive', 'auto', 'ebc', 'greenstuff', '6000', 'series', 'supreme', 'truck', 'and', 'suv', 'brake', 'pads', 'dp61603']
1   ['new', 'free', 'stock', 'photo', 'of', 'city', 'cars', 'road']
```

Code:-

```
g=df['tweets'].astype(str)
go=g.to_string(buf=None, na_rep='NaN', float_format=None, header=True, index=True, length=False, dtype=False, name=False, max_rows=None)
```

Output:-

```
0       ['automotive', 'auto', 'ebc', 'greenstuff', '6...
1       ['new', 'free', 'stock', 'photo', 'of', 'city'...
```

How can I enlarge this and get the complete data?

Comment: You already have the complete data; it is just truncated when being displayed.